# Real time active users in GA

Tags: google-analytics

Looking at Google Analytics Real Time tracking.

Why is there such a difference in the two numbers?

[image: real time users]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Google Analytics bug, it is an accumulation of the number of active users over time without however the total being decreased once the user is no longer in that state. There is nothing to do, it realigns itself.

https://www.analyticstraps.com/bug-numero-anomalo-di-utenti-attivi-in-tempo-reale/